# I have a CNAME pointing to DotCloud and an A record to wwwizer. What should I put in a PTR record for reverse DNS lookups?

Tags: dotcloud

Do I point the PTR to wwwizer's IP address, or to DotCloud? And if I'm pointing it to DotCloud, does that mean I'll need to get a dedicated IP? Thanks.